# Java Changing timezone database to older version using timezone updater tool

Tags: java

Is it possible to change the time zone database of a JDK to older timezone database using the timezone updater tool.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming you are using the Oracle JDK, Oracle provides a TZUpdater tool ([download it here](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/downloads/tzupdater-download-513681.html) or [read the documentation here](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/documentation/tzupdater-readme-136440.html)). It was originally intended to update to the latest data, but they have added a `-l` (for "location") flag to it to indicate where the data should be downloaded from. You can specify any tzdata archive available through `http://`, `https://`, or `file://`. The format of the archive should be the same as what you get from [IANA](http://www.iana.org/time-zones/repository/tzdata-latest.tar.gz) - i.e. a TAR GZ of the plain text files.

You will also have to use the `-f` option, to *force* an update to an older tzdata version.

> java -jar tzupdater.jar -f -l file:///my/old/tzdata/archive.tar.gz

Please do note that the tool will also attempt to get a SHA-512 hash of the archive and verify it... for this reason, your best bet is probably to download the archive, and create the SHA-512 hash yourself. In the example above, it would need to be available at `file:///my/old/tzdata/archive.tar.gz.sha512`