# Is it possible to use 2 timezone databases simultaneously in Java?

Tags: java, java-8, timezone, java-7

Jdk 7 and Jdk 8 uses different timezone databases. Due to some reasons I need to use old time zone database for some set of data only. Is it possible to manually switch timezone databases in java with some workarounds?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31878491/java-changing-timezone-database-to-older-version-using-timezone-updater-tool